# Google Cloud Storage - Move file from one folder to another - By using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-storage

I would like to move a list of file from google storage to another folder:

```
storage_client = storage.Client()
count = 0

# Retrieve all blobs with a prefix matching the file.
bucket=storage_client.get_bucket(BUCKET_NAME)
# List blobs iterate in folder 
blobs=bucket.list_blobs(prefix=GS_FILES_PATH, delimiter='/') # Excluding folder inside bucket
for blob in blobs:
if fnmatch.fnmatch(blob.name, FILE_PREF):
         WHAT CAN GO HERE?
         count += 1
```

The only useful information which I found in Google Documentation is:

- https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/renaming-copying-moving-objects

By this documentation, the only method is to copy from one folder to another and delete it.

1. Any way to actually MOVE files?
2. What is the best way to move all the files based on PREFIX like `*BLABLA*.csv`

P.S. Do not want to use

- `"gsutil mv gs://[SOURCE_BUCKET_NAME]/[SOURCE_OBJECT_NAME]
  gs://[DESTINATION_BUCKET_NAME]/[DESTINATION_OBJECT_NAME]"`

Comment: It states just below the move part that its always a copy and delete. Ther is no other way then to copy your file to your destination path and then delete the source file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be a possible solution, as there is no move_blob function in google.cloud.storage:

```
from google.cloud import storage  

dest_bucket = storage_client.create_bucket(bucket_to)
source_bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_from)
blobs = source_bucket.list_blobs(prefix=GS_FILES_PATH, delimiter='/') #assuming this is tested

for blob in blobs:
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(blob.name, FILE_PREF): #assuming this is tested
        source_bucket.copy_blob(blob,dest_bucket,new_name = blob.name)
        source_bucket.delete_blob(blob.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use method `rename_blob` in `google.cloud.storage.Bucket`, this function moves the file and deletes the old one. **It's necessary that names of files(blobs) are different**
Take a look at the code below:

```py
from google.cloud import storage  

dest_bucket = storage_client.create_bucket(bucket_to)
source_bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_from)
blobs = source_bucket.list_blobs(prefix=GS_FILES_PATH, delimiter='/') #assuming this is tested

for blob in blobs:
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(blob.name, FILE_PREF): #assuming this is tested
        source_bucket.rename_blob(blob,dest_bucket,new_name = blob.name)
```